# SQL query based on condition of null date and a specific value for another field

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an sql query in the form bellow:

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where date_field=null and
another_field=some_specific_value
```

but the part *date_field=null* does not work, i can't return the row with null date with it, what is wrong with my query?

Comment: Null got a very different mean in relational logic and ill confuse any programmer not used to it. I suggest you to take a few minutes to read it: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2829/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might use `IS NULL`. Try this

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.DateField IS NULL AND ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> 
where 
date_field is null and
another_field = some_specific_value
```

Answer (score 1):

use `date_field IS NULL` in place of `date_field=null`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT <column_name> FROM <table_name> WHERE date_field IS NULL AND
 another_field=some_specific_value;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this if you don't want to return null date

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where date_field IS NOT NULL and
another_field=some_specific_value
```

and if want to return date with null

```
select <column_name> from <table_name> where date_field IS NULL and
another_field=some_specific_value
```